# Automatic class decoration (or validation) upon derivation

Tags: python, class, decorator, metaclass

I have a base class from which I derive multiple subclasses.
Each subclass defines class constants, and I wish to enforce certain limitations on them.
For example:

```
class Base(object):
    # define these in your sub-class, and make sure (NOM % DENOM == 0)
    NOMINATOR = None
    DENOMINATOR = None

class Subclass_good(Base):
    NOMINATOR = 6
    DENOMINATOR = 3

class Subclass_bad(Base):
    NOMINATOR = 7
    DENOMINATOR = 5
```

I want to be able to enforce the rule (NOM % DENOM == 0).
I currently do this with a class decorator:

```
def nom_denom_validator(cls):
    assert(cls.NOMINATOR % cls.DENOMINATOR == 0)
    return cls

# and decorate each subclass, e.g.:
@nom_denom_validator
class Subclass_another(Base):
    NOMINATOR = 9
    DENOMINATOR = 12
```

But I don't like the fact that I need to decorate each subclass (I have plenty). I'm interested whether this can be done by some manipulation on the Base class directly.

Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, funny. I was thinking about it for a while, but only after posting the question - specifically when choosing tags, and adding "metaclass" there - did I realize I may have an answer myself.
So, submitted for review and future knowledge, here goes:

```
class Base_Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, class_dict):
        new_type = type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, class_dict)
        if not (new_type.NOMINATOR % new_type.DENOMINATOR) == 0:
            raise Exception("Invalid subclass created - validation failed")
        return new_type

# have Base and all its descendants be enforced:
class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = Base_Metaclass
    # I must pass the validation myself, no None's anymore...
    NOMINATOR = 1
    DENOMINATOR = 1
```

And now all children should be auto-enforced.

Comment: Yep, if you want class-level behavior inherited, you want a metaclass. If you dont' want it inherited, you want a class decorator.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the checking in the base classes constructor

```
class Base(object):
    # define these in your sub-class, and make sure (NOM % DENOM == 0)
    NOMINATOR = None
    DENOMINATOR = None
    def __init__(self):
        assert(self.NOMINATOR % self.DENOMINATOR == 0)
```

When you create an instance of `Subclass_bad()`, you'll get `AssertionError`.

Comment: This will indeed prevent bad instances, but I'm looking to prevent "at compile time" the creation of the invalid sub-class itself.

Comment: You can't do it at compile time: compile time is when you'll catch syntax errors, but the metaclass solution will check when the class is defined at run-time, or checking in the base class constructor will check when the instance is created, also at run-time.

Comment: @Duncan: you are right, of course. I was referring to class object definition at import time, and that's definitely at runtime.